# Get Keytyped event for JMenubar textfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm stacked in my project and I need some help, I'm added jtextfield to the jmenubar. But I couldn't get Keytyped event for the added jtxtfield. If anyone knows how can do that, Please help me.

Here example code:

in the jframe constructor:

```
public NewJFrame1() {




    initComponents();

        JTextField txt1=new JTextField();

     jMenuBar1.add(txt1);


}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using a `KeyListener` on a text component, consider trying a `DocumentListener` instead...mind you, adding a `JTextField` to a `JMenuBar` seems a bit ... weird...

Comment: *"I'm stacked in my project"* :D

Comment: What do you want to happen when a key is typed to the text field? The code you gave has nothing to do with key typed events.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Why is a `JTextField` in a `JMenubar` weird? Eclipse uses it (the Quick Access text field) and I could find quite a few other pictures of GUIs that do this.

Comment: I would tend to see text fields in toolbars more then I would expect to see them within menu bass, but that's just me